# Sum in subtotal using array not working

Tags: javascript, pdf-form

I am using the following code and the result isn't the actual sum of the values, but returns the values in order: $1.00, $2.00, $3.00 shows 123.00, not the expected $6.00

```js
var oFldSub = this.getField("Sub");
if(oFldSub != null)
{
   var  aLineSub = oFldSub.getArray();
   var sum = 0;
   for(var i=0;i<aLineSub;i++)
   {
       if(!isNaN(aLineSub[i].value))
          sum += aLineSub[i].value;
   }
   event.value = sum;
}
else
   app.alert("Form Error");
```

Comment: Your snippet may give you the answer:
`"message": "Uncaught TypeError: this.getField is not a function",`

Comment: i guess that `aLineSub[i].value` return string, so try convert it to int: `parseInt(aLineSub[i].value)`

Comment: Rainmx93 that didn't work. I get a Syntax Error: invalid label

Comment: Michael, I saw the error, but do not know how to fix.

Comment: then try: `parseFloat(aLineSub[i].value)`

Comment: parseFloat gives me a result of 0.

Comment: do this  `sum += +aLineSub[i].value;`

Comment: sum += +aLineSub[i].value; is the line that I have already.  If this.getField is not a function, then I am not sure what to try next.  I copied this code from a forum that had a similar situation that I am dealing with, but it doesn't work.